# Detecting Key Presses in Xcode Playground

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sprite-kit, keypress

### The Aim

I am trying to find a way to detect key presses in an Xcode playground (MacOS). (Like the arrow keys). I am trying to achieve this with SpriteKit, if that is at all possible.

### What I have already tried

I have already looked online and found things about `keyUp`. But I am unsure of how I would integrate this into a playground.

*Please note: I am asking for help specifically in **Xcode playgrounds**, not the Swift Playgrounds app on iPad.*